# Ruby on Rails - Rubocop throwing Lint/Syntax: unexpected token tCOMMA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lint, rubocop

Rubocop is throwing this error:

```
Lint/Syntax: unexpected token tCOMMA
(Using Ruby 3.2 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
      render (:new, status: :unprocessable_entity)
```

Here is what the code looks like:

```
def create
    @company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)

    if @company.save
      redirect_to(company_url(@company), { notice: "Company was successfully updated." })
    else
      render (:new, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
```

Even when changing it back to `render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity` it ask me to change it to `render (:new, status: :unprocessable_entity)`, i have tried everything under the sun but still no luck

Any help would be much appreciated i am able to invite you to my GitHub if you wish to look further

Comment: The space after `render` makes Ruby interpret the parentheses as "expression grouping parentheses" not "method calling parentheses".

Comment: `render(:new, status: :unprocessable_entity)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a RuboCop issue, running it with `ruby -w` reports it as invalid.

The problem is the space after `render`. Remove that and it's valid.

Comment: that has worked thankyou very much